# Cannot show values when editing restful form in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When editing form in laravel I cannot view  the values being passed on the form. When i inputted values it successfully added to the table. However when I want to edit the values, they are not visible. However when I call the value outside the inputs form I can view the value.

See my code below.Can someone please help me. Thank you.

```
       create.blade.php
       <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">New Report Form</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @include('errors.list')
                    @include('partials.success')
                    {!!    Form::open(['route'=>'crime_reports.store','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}

                         @include('crimereports._form')

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
                            {!! Form::submit('Save Changes', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-md']) !!}
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer ">
                    <p><small>Crime Chase</small></p>
                </div>
```

edit.php

```
                {!! Form::model('$crime_edit',['method' => 'PATCH','route'=>['crime_reports.update',$crime_edit->id],
                    'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}

                @include('crimereports._form')

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
                        {!! Form::submit('Update Form', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-md']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer ">
                <p><small>Crime Chase</small></p>
            </div>
```

crimereportcontroller

```
        public function store(CrimeNewReportRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    CrimeReport::create($input);
   // $input = CrimeReport::create($request->all());

   // return redirect('crime_reports')->withSuccess("Fields were inserted!");
    return redirect()->back();
}  
      public function edit($id)
{
    $crime_edit = CrimeReport::findOrFail($id);

    return view('crimereports.edit',compact('crime_edit',$crime_edit));
}
```

_form

```
   <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('crime_victim', 'Victim Name',['class'=>'col-md-3 control-     label']) !!}
 <div class="col-md-8">
     {!! Form::text('crime_victim', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
        'placeholder' => 'Enter Victim name']) !!}      
</div>
```

```
   <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('crime_suspect', 'Suspect Name',['class'=>'col-md-3 control-label']) !!}

<div class="col-md-8">
     {!! Form::text('crime_suspect', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
        'placeholder' => 'Enter Suspect Name']) !!}       
</div>
```

```
      <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('suspect_description','List Description' ,['class'=>'col-md-3 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-md-8">

     {!! Form::textarea('suspect_description', null, ['class'=>'form-control',
        'placeholder'=>'Details about suspect']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Form-model binding, you should be passing the model as the argument. You were close. You have the `$crime_edit` model, but for some reason, you passed it as a string.

Changing this

```
{!! Form::model('$crime_edit',
```

to this should fix your problem:

```
{!! Form::model($crime_edit,
```